# Scrapy's HTMLXPathSelector cause 'segmentation fault' when parsing html page

Tags: python, scrapy

The 'segmentation fault' happens, and scrapy stop running.
After checking the website url, I found it should belong to one tag with
href attribute but no value. like this: " `<a href> dummy </a>` "
I suspect this is caused by lxml .so lib, how to deal with this? At
least prevent the spider stop issue.
My code snippet:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
sites = hxs.select('//a')
for site in sites:
   list_title= site.select('text()').extract()
   list_link = site.select('./@href').extract() #????(crash here when parsing <a href></a>)
```

BTW, The site scraped is 'http://mil.news.sohu.com/'
Running Environment: scrapy 0.15.1 and python 2.7.3, pre-install openssl0.12 because the openssl0.13 default for scrapy doesn't install sucessfully.

thanks a lot
Aaron

Comment: Would the correct XPath for the href perhaps be `@href`?

Comment: @href and ./@href both work for well-formed HTML. Could you test this in your machine?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue. This is caused by libxml2 version 2.6.26 which is default installed by scrapy. Update libxml2 to 2.7.4, solved.

Answer (score 0):

Either they reintroduced the bug or there must be another thing causing this:

```
me:~$ scrapy version -v
Scrapy  : 0.16.3
lxml    : 3.0.2.0
libxml2 : 2.7.8
Twisted : 12.0.0
```